# Match mock-$httpBackend data from $resource service in jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-resource, httpbackend

## Simply Put:

Can I match mock-$httpBackend data from $resource service in a jasmine unit test? How would I do it?

## What I Want:

When I Jasmine-test my backend services with $httpBackend and the $http service, I can do this:

```
  it("should return movie search data from the title", function() {
    var movieData = { title: "The Phantom Menace", description: "A movie.";
    var response = [];

    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?v=1&s=the%20phantom%20menace')
      .respond(200, movieData);

    moviesService.search('the phantom menace')
      .then(function onSuccess(data) {
        response = data;
      });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(response.data).toEqual(movieData);
  }); // end it
```

I have all of The Phantom Menace's information stored in **movieData**. This test passes because it compares the data that is received from the mock backend to what it should be (movieData).

## What I Am Getting:

When I Jasmine-test my backend services with $httpBackend and the $resource service, things are different.

```
 it("retrieves a bunch objects", function() {
    var result = {}, testArray = [];
    var dataToCheck = [
      { id: 1, "des": "This is one."},
      { id: 2, "des": "This is two."},
      { id: 3, "des": "This is three."}
    ];

    $httpBackend.whenGET('movies/api')
      .respond(dataToCheck);

    MovieResource.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
      result = data;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    angular.forEach(result, function (resource) {
      testArray.push(resource);
    })

    expect(testArray).toEqual(dataToCheck);
  }); // end it
```

Karma tells me:

> Expected [ Resource({ id: 1, des: 'This is one.' }), Resource({ id: 2,
>   des: 'This is two.' }), Resource({ id: 3, des: 'This is three.' }) ]
>   to equal [ Object({ id: 1, des: 'This is one.' }), Object({ id: 2,
>   des: 'This is two.' }), Object({ id: 3, des: 'This is three.' }) ].

So, instead of "Objects" they are "Resources."

I appreciate ANY guidance you can give me.

Comment: Is it possible to cast the JSON objects in dataToCheck as Resources?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this

```
expect(testArray[0].id).toEqual(dataToCheck[0].id);
expect(testArray[1].id).toEqual(dataToCheck[1].id);
expect(testArray[0].des).toEqual(datatoCheck[0].des);
```

Reference:
http://accraze.info/testing-angular-services-using-jasmine/